# Cannot access Flask with apache

Tags: python, flask

I have a linux server which I am running my flask app on it like this:

```
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

Inside the server I can access it like this:

`curl http://0.0.0.0:5000/photo` (and I am getting a valid response)

However, when I am trying to access it outside the server:

`http://my_ip:5000/photo` - the connection is refused.

The same ip, will return an image saved on public_html with apache2 configured

```
http://my_ip/public_html/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png
```

Comment: I have a suspicion you have a firewall on your Linux machine that is blocking port 5000. I would install nginx for proxying and configure it so that `http://my_ip/photo` would forward traffic to and from `http://127.0.0.1:5000/photo`.

Comment: Thanks, can you post it as a proper answer so I could accept it?

Comment: Done. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a suspicion you have a firewall on your Linux machine that is blocking port 5000.

**Solution 1:**

Open the relevant port on your firewall.

**Solution 2:**

I would suggest you to install `nginx` as a web proxy and configure it so that *http://my_ip/photo* would forward traffic to and from *http://127.0.0.1:5000/photo*:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /photo {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/photo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this simple snippet to get the ip-address from the interface

```
import socket    
def get_ip_address():
        """ get ip-address of interface being used """
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
        return s.getsockname()[0]

IP = get_ip_address()
```

And in main:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=IP, port=PORT, debug=False)
```

And running:

```
./app.py
 * Running on http://10.2.0.41:1443/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Comment: I tried the solution but I still cannot access it from outside.

Comment: Have you opened up the firewall on the port?, flask run their own web server so apache works as a proxy.